# CUDA 5.0 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol for cuda methods

Tags: c++, linker, cuda, nsight

I have error in linker

```
1>ManifestResourceCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>kernel.cu.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cudaMalloc@8
1>kernel.cu.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cudaFree@4
```

I saw similar question added here :
[Unresolved external symbols in beginners CUDA program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061715/unresolved-external-symbols-in-beginners-cuda-program)
But it's already have added this information to linker.

So where is the problem ?
I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Premium with CUDA SDK 5.0 and Nsight 3.0 for VS

Source code here : http://pastebin.com/DfdfSfWd
(It's a example generated by Visual Studio on created new project for CUDA 5.0)

[EDIT]

Settings for Linker

> Configuration Properties->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories :
>
> $(CudaToolkitLibDir) $(CUDA_LIB_PATH) $(CUDA_PATH)\lib\$(PlatformName)
>
> Configuration Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies
>
> cuda.lib;cudart.lib; and the other libs..

But in properties I see that CUDA haves own Linder, "CUDA Linker" and that doesnt have set

> Additional Library Directories

and

> Additional Dependencies

so I set this properties but nothing that change, the linker still have problem.

[EDIT]

Ok, the error is when I change

> Configuration Properties->CUDA C/C++->Device->Code Generation

from

> compute_10,sm_10

to

> compute_20,sm_20

and add a flag -dc for CUDA C/C++

Comment: Your source code doesn't matter all that much. What are your linker settings? Which libraries did you include?

Comment: Is `cudaart.lib` a typo in your question? The library is called `cudart.lib`.

Comment: sorry my mistake made here but in project is okay. Please see last edit (that cause problem)

Comment: The Problem is that I want to do "Separate Compilation & Linking" where it is enabled in CUDA 5.0, but I don't how to correct set on in my project for Visual Studio.

Comment: Ok know I have one error : 
1>kernel.cu.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_41_tmpxft_000013b4_00000000_5_kernel_cpp1_ii_f853efa9 referenced in function "void __cdecl __sti____cudaRegisterAll_41_tmpxft_000013b4_00000000_5_kernel_cpp1_ii_f853efa9(void)" (?__sti____cudaRegisterAll_41_tmpxft_000013b4_00000000_5_kernel_cpp1_ii_f853efa9@@YAXXZ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found how to set the project for Separate Compilation & Linking, below we have an example of project where it work :
[example simpleSeparateCompilation](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/C/Projects/x64/simpleSeparateCompilation.zip)