# CUDA 6.5: error MSB3191 Unable to create directory and LNK2001 Unresolved External symbol

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, cuda, linker-errors

I am running CUDA 6.5 on Visual Studio 2013 x64.

I have a VC++ static library project named MyLib which is linked with MyClient x64 console executable project. I added CUDA 6.5 build customization to both the projects. In addition, I goto Configuration Properties -> CUDA C/C++ and have set “Target Machine Platform” as 64-bit for these two projects as I want to compile them for x64 platform

I added MyCUDACode.cpp and MyCUDACode.h files to MyLib project and marked their item type as CUDA C/C++ instead oc C/C++ compiler. MyCUDACode.cpp has number of functions which call CUDA API functions. Also, MyCUDACode.h references the cuda.h and cuda_runtime.h files.

MyClient is linked with MyLib. I now get two compilation errors:

- First error in compiling MyLib which says a Unable to create directory
- Second, I get unresolved external symbol errors while linking
  MyClient with MyLib. Here is the log output:

  ------ Build started: Project: MyLib, Configuration: Release x64 ------
  1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 6.5.targets(412,9): error MSB3191: Unable to create directory "x64\Release\D:\github\src\helpers\". The given path's format is not supported.

  2>------ Build started: Project: MyClient, Configuration: Release x64 ------
  2>MyLib.lib(MyCUDACode.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol cudaGetDeviceCount

  2>MyLib.lib(MyCUDACode.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol cudaDeviceCanAccessPeer

  2>MyLib.lib(MyCUDACode.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol cudaGetDeviceProperties

  2>MyLib.lib(MyCUDACode.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol cudaSetDevice

  2>MyLib.lib(MyCUDACode.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol cudaDeviceDisablePeerAccess

  2>MyLib.lib(MyCUDACode.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol cudaDeviceReset

  2>MyLib.lib(MyCUDACode.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol cudaDeviceEnablePeerAccess

  2>C:...\visual studio 2013\Projects\Prj\x64\Release\MyClient.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 7 unresolved externals

I have tried both release and debug modes but I get same error.

Comment: Did you look at the very first line of the error message. You have a badly malformed path somewhere in your project set up.

Comment: I can see that: ""x64\Release\D:\github\src\helpers\"". This particular folder "D:\github\src\helpers\" has  MyCUDACode.h and  MyCUDACode.cpp files. But I am not sure why the VS is using this path

Comment: As I checked the BuildCustomizations\CUDA 6.5.targets(412,9) file, I see the following:         <MakeDir
            Condition="'%(CudaCompile.ExcludedFromBuild)' != 'true'"
            Directories="%(CudaCompile.DepsOutputDir)" />

Comment: @talonmies: I created two sample projects (console and static library) projects from scratch and added CUDA 6.5 customization to it. Now I donot get the MSB3191: Unable to create directory", but I still do get the unresolved external symbol errors

Comment: Ok, I found how to resolve the external symbols error. Just follow this text: Settings for Linker

Configuration Properties->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories :

$(CudaToolkitLibDir) $(CUDA_LIB_PATH) $(CUDA_PATH)\lib\$(PlatformName)

Configuration Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies

cuda.lib;cudart.lib; and the other libs..

Comment: In addition, The only way to remove the error MSB3191: Unable to create directory is by marking the cpp and header files as C/C++ instead of CUDA C/C++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am just reproducing the steps to resolve the errors:

- To resolve the error(temporary workaround): **MSB3191: Unable to create directory The given path's format is not supported.**, simply copy Cuda cu and cuh files to Visual studio project folder.
- **[UPDATE]**: I recently found a better solution for the issue **MSB3191: Unable to create directory The given path's format is not supported.**. This fix works without need to move around the cu files to the VS project folder. For this, open the file **"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 6.5.targets"**, and move to the offending line(412 in this case). This line contains following xml section:

  ```
  <MakeDir
      Condition="'%(CudaCompile.ExcludedFromBuild)' != 'true'"
      Directories="%(CudaCompile.DepsOutputDir)" />
  ```

  As you can see, this is a sort of directive which tells the build system to make a folder for the cuda files being compiled. The property used for folder name is CudaCompile.DepsOutputDir. Now open the file: **"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 6.5.props"**. This props file defines values of the properties used in targets file. Now search for word **DepsOutputDir**in this props file. There are only XML section which defines and refers to this keyword is:

  ```
      <!-- Miscellaneous -->
      <DepsOutputFile>%(Filename)%(Extension).deps</DepsOutputFile>
      <DepsOutputDir>$(IntDir)%(RelativeDir)</DepsOutputDir>
      <DepsOutputPath>%(DepsOutputDir)%(DepsOutputFile)</DepsOutputPath>
  ```

  Now, to finally fix the MSB3191 issue, simply remove the variable **%(RelativeDir)** from above xml section and save the props file (this would require administrative privileges)
- To resolve the error: **LNK2001: unresolved external symbol**, follow the **Settings for Linker** section in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13900798/cuda-5-0-error-lnk2001-unresolved-external-symbol-for-cuda-methods)