# Unresolved external symbol _parallel_manager referenced in function _main

Tags: visual-studio-2015, cuda

When trying to compile a program including a CUDA file, I get an error code of LNK2019, but I specifically made sure to include the relevant header file at the beginning of the code:

```
#include "parallel_functions.cuh"
```

Which consists entirely of:

```
#ifndef parallel_functions_cuh
#define parallel_functions_cuh

void
parallel_manager(image_chunk ***image_grid, network_chunk *** network_grid);

#endif
```

With an earlier program it was simple enough for me to include everything in one file (which removed the linker errors) but with this program that would not be a valid option.

The only reference I can find to this particular error with CUDA are in [this prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061715/unresolved-external-symbols-in-beginners-cuda-program) but the solutions there are already applied, with all libraries included.

The same error occurs in the simple example project consisting of launch.c, kernel.cu, and kernel.cuh.

launch.c:

```
#include "kernel.cuh"

void main()
{
    parallel_function();
}
```

kernel.cuh:

```
#ifndef kernel_cuh
#define kernel_cuh

void parallel_function();

#endif
```

kernel.cu:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void kernel(char *a)
{
    a[threadIdx.x] = threadIdx.x;
}

void parallel_function()
{
    char* data;
    cudaMallocManaged(&data, 256);

    kernel<<<1, 256>>>(data);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", data[i]);
    }

    cudaFree(data);
}
```

Which gives the following build output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ErrorProject, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  launch.c
1>launch.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _parallel_function referenced in function _main
1>C:\Error\ErrorProject\Debug\ErrorProject.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

With the error list furthermore containing this:

```
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _parallel_function referenced in function _main
```

The build dependencies use the default CUDA V8.0 targets, including the toolkit dependencies and cudart.lib in the linker settings.

Comment: This is a linker error.  There is some file that either needs to be added to this project that includes the definition of `parallel_manager`, or else you need to link your project against an object or library that contains the compiled version of that function.  Simply including the header file that provides the function declaration is not enough to avoid a link time error.  There may be a file called `parallel_functions.cu` for example, that is not currently part of your project but needs to be.

Comment: parallel_functions.cu is already part of the project.

Comment: It may be necessary to see a complete example that demonstrates this, then.  You should be able to strip it down to just the file that includes this header file, the header file itself, and the parallel_functions.cu file.  I'm sure it's possible that you have some windows VS project setting that is interfering as well.  In that case, providing the full VS console output that shows this error and all the compile commands leading up to it may help

Comment: change `launch.c` to `launch.cpp`.  and there is no evidence in the build output that `kernel.cu` is actually part of your project.  It's not being compiled anywhere.  I also recommend not building 32-bit projects using CUDA anymore.

Comment: I realised that I missed out part of the build output, but that did resolve the compilation issue, thank you.

Comment: This is arguably a duplicate of many questions here on the SO `cuda` tag, such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553015/cuda-c-linker-error-undefined-reference).  I've provided a CW answer so as not to get into arguments about duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, this appears to have been a mismatch between C-style linking and C++-style linking (also probably evident from the unresolved symbol itself -- which does not appear to be [mangled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Real-world_effects_of_C.2B.2B_name_mangling)).

`nvcc` uses C++-style compiling and linking.  C-style functionality can be accommodated but requires special handling, which is covered [in many places here on the CUDA tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553015/cuda-c-linker-error-undefined-reference) and elsewhere, so I'll not repeat that here.

By default, a number of compilers (apparently including the host compiler here) treat filenames ending in `.c` as implicitly specifying C-style linking.  As a result, the requested function in OP's source file (launch.c) could not be resolved against a provider elsewhere in the project, which was providing C++-style link points.

A possible solution in this case was to rename the `launch.c` to `launch.cpp`, which converted to C++ style linking for the whole project, resulting in consistency.